# Make drop down list items unavailable once selected?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio

I'm using a drop down menu, and I'd like to make an item unavailable once it's been selected. Is there a method for that? As of now, the only action I have on it is a visible=true on some input form panels. I'm using C# and ASP.NET in visual studio 2010. Fair warning: if it isn't obvious from the nature of my question, this is actually my first go-round in the world of programming, so an advanced concept in an answer may just inspire more questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do Code with the Item
    if(comboBox1.SelectedItem != null) //I forgot that ,better to prevent
    comboBox1.Items.Remove(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
}
```

Comment: `drop down menu`, not a combo box.

Comment: Yeah, dropdown list instead of combo box, but it works perfectly. Many thanks, @Burim.

Comment: +1 for divining he was talking about a combo box instead of a menu!

Comment: No, it was a dropdown list. Problem, now that the the switch case block I wrote to display the product forms doesn't fire. What's that about?

Comment: Solved it. I incorporated @Burim's method into the switch cases themselves. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in a drop-down menu, you intercept the OnOpening event and either set Visible=false or Enabled=false just before the menu opens.  It sounds like you want to disable *after* the menu item was selected? Just put Enabled = false at the end of your item selected handler